# For my "switch on light with clap project " will sound sensors detect other sounds other than a clap and switch on the light?

Tags: sensors, arduino, sound

I am just a high school student who is trying to self-learn for my IoT home automation projects.Please excuse me if this question sound silly to you.This time I am working on this "clap to switch on the light" project.
I learnt that to detect the sound from the clap, I can use a sound sensor.In my case, the sensor will be connected to an Arduino UNO which will then be connected to a relay module that will control the lights.My question is: Will the light switch-on because of a loud sound other than a clap, because obviously it would be really annoying for the light to switch on and off when I don't want it to.

Comment: to differentiate between sounds, you will need to analyze the frequency spectrum of a detected sound as well as the attack and decay of the sound...... research `arduino fft` .............. https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2017/08/what-is-fft-and-how-can-you-implement-it-on-an-arduino/

Comment: more info here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoSoundClapDetector and here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoSoundWhistleDetector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it will detect other sounds in the sense of noticing other sounds — that's what a sound sensor is for. Getting the trigger exact enough will probably be the most challenging part of the project — unless there is a library that detects the sound profile of claps.

That shouldn't deter you though. It's just about refining the detection bit by bit. Just know that you'll have misfires in the detection in the beginning. A lot.

The first Amazon Echos were quite bad at properly detecting the wake words. Nowadays they can detect it a few rooms away, while the tap is running, and the TV, and the Police drives by with sirens.